# Can't build wheel and single-version-externally-managed not recognized error on pip install pythonnet WSL 2 VS Code

Tags: python-wheel, python.net

I am on WSL2 in VS Code. Using Zsh on VS Code.

I am trying to install pythonnet though am getting two errors:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

This is from using pip install pythonnet==2.5.2

My versions are:
Python 3.8.10
Wheel 0.37.0
Mono: 6.8.0.105
pycparser 2.20

I have searched high and low online though I can't find a solution - everything seems to point to updating wheel and installing mono - as you can see from the above version numbers, I have them installed.
I am doing everything from within a virtual env.

Does anyone have any experience with this or know what to do to get past these errors?

Full log:

>  ~/j/s/stx1alpha-signals/d/backend on   master !6 ?1 ❯ pip install
> pythonnet==2.5.2                                             
> stx1alpha at  10:52:05 AM Collecting pythonnet==2.5.2   Using cached
> pythonnet-2.5.2.tar.gz (1.9 MB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
> done Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in
> /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
> (from pythonnet==2.5.2) (2.20) Building wheels for collected packages:
> pythonnet   Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error   ERROR:
> Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/bin/python -u -c
> 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-789kx5l4
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/
> Complete output (153 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_ext   Checking for updates from
> https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.   Currently running NuGet.exe 4.1.0.
> Updating NuGet.exe to 5.11.0.   Update successful.   MSBuild
> auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from
> '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin'.
>
> > > > > xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<
> > > > > MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified
> > > > > WARNING: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects
> > > > > will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.
> > > > > Restoring NuGet package System.ValueTuple.4.5.0.   Restoring NuGet
> > > > > package NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1.   Restoring NuGet package
> > > > > NUnit.3.12.0.   Restoring NuGet package UnmanagedExports.1.2.7.
> > > > > Adding package 'NUnit.3.12.0' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Adding package 'System.ValueTuple.4.5.0' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Adding package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Adding package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Added package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Added package 'System.ValueTuple.4.5.0' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Added package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'   Added package 'NUnit.3.12.0' to folder
> > > > > '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/packages'
> > > > > NuGet Config files used:
> > > > > /home/jessica-ryan/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config
> > > > > Feeds used:
> > > > > /home/jessica-ryan/.nuget/packages/
> > > > > https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
> > > > > Installed:
> > > > > 4 package(s) to packages.config projects
>
> > > > > xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<
> > > > > XBuild Engine Version 14.0   Mono, Version 6.8.0.105   Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
> > > > > Build started 11/18/2021 10:53:28.   __________________________________________________   Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln"
> > > > > (Clean target(s)):
> > > > > Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
> > > > > Building solution configuration "ReleaseMono|x64".
> > > > > Target Clean:
> > > > > Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj"
> > > > > (Clean target(s)):
> > > > > Target CoreClean:
> > > > > Deleting file '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/obj/x64/ReleaseMono/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
> > > > > Done building project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj".
> > > > > The project 'clrmodule' is disabled for solution configuration 'ReleaseMono|x64'.
> > > > > Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/testing/Python.Test.csproj"
> > > > > (Clean target(s)):
> > > > > Target CoreClean:
> > > > > Deleting file '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/testing/obj/x64/ReleaseMono/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
> > > > > Done building project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/testing/Python.Test.csproj".
> > > > > Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/embed_tests/Python.EmbeddingTest.csproj"
> > > > > (Clean target(s)):
> > > > > Target CoreClean:
> > > > > Deleting file '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/embed_tests/obj/x64/ReleaseMono/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
> > > > > Done building project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/embed_tests/Python.EmbeddingTest.csproj".
> > > > > Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/console/Console.csproj"
> > > > > (Clean target(s)):
> > > > > Target CoreClean:
> > > > > Deleting file '/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/console/obj/x64/ReleaseMono/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
> > > > > Done building project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/console/Console.csproj".
> > > > > Done building project
> > > > > "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln".
> > > > > Build succeeded.
> > > > > 0 Warning(s)
> > > > > 0 Error(s)
> > > > > Time Elapsed 00:00:00.3407830
>
> > > > > xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<
> > > > > XBuild Engine Version 14.0   Mono, Version 6.8.0.105   Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
> > > > > Build started 11/18/2021 10:53:29.   __________________________________________________   Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln"
> > > > > (Build target(s)):
> > > > > Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
> > > > > Building solution configuration "ReleaseMono|x64".
> > > > > Target Build:
> > > > > Project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj"
> > > > > (default target(s)):
> > > > > Target PrepareForBuild:
> > > > > Configuration: ReleaseMono Platform: x64
> > > > > Created directory "bin/"
> > > > > Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
> > > > > No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
> > > > > Target CoreCompile:
> > > > > Tool /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mcs.exe execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:pdbonly /optimize+
> > > > > /out:obj/x64/ReleaseMono/Python.Runtime.dll
> > > > > /resource:obj/x64/ReleaseMono/Python.Runtime.resources.clr.py,clr.py
> > > > > Codecs/EncoderGroup.cs Codecs/DecoderGroup.cs
> > > > > Codecs/RawProxyEncoder.cs Codecs/TupleCodecs.cs converterextensions.cs
> > > > > finalizer.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs ../SharedAssemblyInfo.cs
> > > > > arrayobject.cs assemblymanager.cs BorrowedReference.cs classderived.cs
> > > > > classbase.cs classmanager.cs classobject.cs clrobject.cs
> > > > > codegenerator.cs constructorbinder.cs constructorbinding.cs
> > > > > converter.cs CustomMarshaler.cs debughelper.cs delegatemanager.cs
> > > > > delegateobject.cs eventbinding.cs eventobject.cs exceptions.cs
> > > > > extensiontype.cs fieldobject.cs generictype.cs genericutil.cs
> > > > > importhook.cs indexer.cs interfaceobject.cs interfaces.cs interop.cs
> > > > > iterator.cs managedtype.cs metatype.cs methodbinder.cs
> > > > > methodbinding.cs methodobject.cs methodwrapper.cs
> > > > > modulefunctionobject.cs moduleobject.cs modulepropertyobject.cs
> > > > > nativecall.cs NewReference.cs NonCopyableAttribute.cs overload.cs
> > > > > propertyobject.cs pyansistring.cs pydict.cs PyExportAttribute.cs
> > > > > pyfloat.cs pyint.cs pyiter.cs pylist.cs pylong.cs pynumber.cs
> > > > > pyobject.cs pyscope.cs pysequence.cs pystring.cs pythonengine.cs
> > > > > pythonexception.cs pytuple.cs ReferenceExtensions.cs runtime.cs
> > > > > typemanager.cs typemethod.cs Util.cs platform/Types.cs
> > > > > platform/LibraryLoader.cs polyfill/ReflectionPolifills.cs
> > > > > slots/mp_length.cs interop38.cs
> > > > > obj/x64/ReleaseMono/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs
> > > > > /target:library /unsafe+
> > > > > /define:"PYTHON38;PYTHON3;UCS4;MONO_LINUX;PYTHON_WITHOUT_ENABLE_SHARED"
> > > > > /nowarn:1591 /doc:bin/Python.Runtime.xml /langversion:7.3 /nostdlib
> > > > > /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0-api/System.dll
> > > > > /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0-api/System.Core.dll
> > > > > /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0-api//mscorlib.dll   CSC: error CS1617:
> > > > > Invalid -langversion option `7.3'. It must be` ISO-1', `ISO-2',
> > > > > Default, Latest or value in range 1 to 7.2
> > > > > Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
> > > > > Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj".--
> > > > > FAILED
> > > > > Done building project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj".--
> > > > > FAILED
> > > > > Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
> > > > > Done building target "Build" in project "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln".-- FAILED   Done building project
> > > > > "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln".-- FAILED
> > > > > Build FAILED.   Errors:
> > > > > /tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/pythonnet.sln
> > > > > (Build) ->   (Build target) ->
> > > > > /tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/src/runtime/Python.Runtime.csproj
> > > > > (default targets) ->
> > > > > /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile
> > > > > target) ->
>
> ```
>     CSC: error CS1617: Invalid -langversion option `7.3'. It must be `ISO-1', `ISO-2', Default, Latest or value in range 1 to 7.2
>
>      0 Warning(s)
>      1 Error(s)
>  Time Elapsed 00:00:00.3647620   Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> File "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 630, in 
> setup(
> File "/home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
> line 153, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py",
> line 612, in run
> return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
> File "/home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 299, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
> self.build_extensions()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
> self._build_extensions_serial()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
> self.build_extension(ext)
> File "/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py",
> line 353, in build_extension
> subprocess.check_call(" ".join(cmd + ["/t:Build"]), shell=use_shell)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'xbuild pythonnet.sln
> /p:Configuration=ReleaseMono /p:Platform=x64
> /p:DefineConstants="PYTHON38%3BPYTHON3%3BUCS4%3BMONO_LINUX%3BPYTHON_WITHOUT_ENABLE_SHARED"
> /p:PythonBuildDir="/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8"
> /p:PythonInteropFile="interop38.cs" /p:PackageId=pythonnet_py38_x64
> /verbosity:normal /t:Build' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet   Running setup.py clean for pythonnet Failed to
> build pythonnet Installing collected packages: pythonnet
> Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/bin/python -u -c
> 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record /tmp/pip-record-2fxmdkst/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/include/site/python3.8/pythonnet
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/
> Complete output (6 lines):
> usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
> or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
> or: setup.py --help-commands
> or: setup.py cmd --help
>
> ```
> error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> ```
>
> /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/bin/python -u -c
> 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mlymh9lo/pythonnet_eef24e9bf71f4dcdacdc5897c9504adf/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record /tmp/pip-record-2fxmdkst/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jessica-ryan/jessica-ryan/stx1alpha/.venv/include/site/python3.8/pythonnet
> Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a newer version of Mono. The one you have does not support C# 7.3 that Pythonnet build needs.

Comment: Thank you. Despite installing Mono yesterday, I installed an older version. You were correct. I followed https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mono-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and updated to version Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.122. Pythonet installed successfully :)